# Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, php, sdk, activex, fingerprint

I am using a SDK ([Finger Print SDK](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/fingerprint_sdk)) which is used to integrate finger print scanner with my application. 
The application is working fine in my local server environment but not on the web server.The application uses activeX which i have already enabled. When ever i am trying to run the SDK it gives an error `Object doesn't support property or method 'Initialize'`.I did some r & d and reset my IE settings to default but it didn't work. So what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `Iniatialize` is misspelled?

Comment: it is possibly a library issue. check that your environment has the same as those on the web server

Comment: I have checked it again and the same working fine on my local server. And here is my code                                                                       var url_server="http://localhost/finger_reader/server-side/"

 //Initializes the Fingerprint SDK library and the Capture
 function Initialize() {
  try
  {
  
  
  GrFingerX.Initialize();
  
  GrFingerX.CapInitialize();
  
  }
  catch (e)
  {
  alert(e);
  }
 }

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. This is library issue. I am using xampp on my local and lamp on my web server. But i am not able to spot out difference between the two servers. So is there any way that could help me? Is there any possibility that Lamp does not run application on the client machine.Do i need to provide some additional settings?